# How viewmodel and view communicates?

Tags: ios, swift, solid-principles

recently i was reading about dependency inversion principle, which states that high level module should not depend low level module, they both should depends upon abstraction.

```
protocol ViewControllerProtocol {
    func saveButtonTapped()
}

struct ViewModel : ViewControllerProtocol{
    func saveButtonTapped() {
        //save data...
        print("forward save request")
    }

     func statusArrived(){
       // inform viewcontroller about updating UI
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var  vm : ViewControllerProtocol?

    required init(viewmodel : ViewModel){
        self.vm = viewmodel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)
    }

    @IBAction func btnSaveTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        vm?.saveButtonTapped()
    }


}
```

following dependency inversion principle, i am able to communicate between viewcontroller -> Viewmodel.

my question is, how to communicate in reverse direction ? ie. form view model to view controller ?
i am thinking, by creating another protocol, and viewcontroller implements that protocol....

how to communicate in reverse direction ? ie. form view model to view controller ?

Answer (score 2):

**Add a closure as a completion handler**

```
protocol ViewControllerProtocol {
     func saveButtonTapped(completionHandler: ()->())
 }
```

**Implementation**

```
struct ViewModel : ViewControllerProtocol{
    func saveButtonTapped(completionHandler: () -> ()) {
        print("forward save request")

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

**This is how you can use now:-**

```
@IBAction func btnSaveTapped(_ sender: Any) {
     vm?.saveButtonTapped { [weak self] in

         /// From ViewModel -> ViewController
     }
 }
```

**Don't forget to add a capture list to avoid retain cycle if you will use viewController inside that closure.**

Comment: but what if VM want to inform VC inside func statusArrived() ?

Comment: Please check the edited post, you can use the same implementation for `statusArrived()` as well.

Comment: thank you this is the answer I was waiting for, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You use closures to return the call.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var  vm : ViewControllerProtocol?

    required init(viewmodel : ViewModel){
        self.vm = viewmodel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)

        self.vm.savedSuccessfully = {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnSaveTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        vm?.saveButtonTapped()
    }


}

struct ViewModel : ViewControllerProtocol{

    var savedSuccesfully: (() -> ())?
    func saveButtonTapped() {
        //save data...
        print("forward save request")
    }

     func statusArrived(){
       // inform viewcontroller about updating UI
       savedSuccesfully?()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using delegate pattern to communicate from ViewModel to View is fine as long as the ViewModel does not own the View, i.e there is no strong reference to the View.

As an alternative solution, you can also look at the Observer Pattern to pass messages from the ViewModel to View. In fact, this is what libraries like RxSwift provide you with.

If you ever look at the class diagram showing dependency inversion, in the case of MVVM, the association from ViewModel to View is always shown in the dotted line with an arrow pointing towards View. This simply means that the ViewModel knows about View but it does not have any strong reference to it.

Comment: yeah, i think dependency inversion includes : both should depend upon abstraction. so i am thinking protocol better way (as it doesn't hold strong reference for VC). your thoughts ?

Comment: but then it will be like cycle, VM implement VC based protocol, VC implement VM based protocol. although both of them have weak references.

Comment: In your implementation, a cycle isn't bad as long as there is one weak reference in it.

Comment: Actually your ViewController/View will hold a strong reference to the ViewModel and ViewModel will hold a weak reference to the ViewController. ViewController needs to implement the ViewModel Protocols to receive messages from ViewModel. If ViewController needs to send some message to ViewModel it can just call one of its methods. If you decide to create abstractions for both then obviously both will have to implement each other's protocols. The important thing here would be how will you provide dependencies. My suggestion is to use Construction Injections using failable initializers.